# "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a simple code in AWS Lambda for listing my buckets

```
import boto3
import botocore

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.list_buckets()
print('Existing buckets:')
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
    print(f'  {bucket["Name"]}')
```

When I Deploy and test it, it gives me the right logs (my list of buckets) but it also gives me the error

> Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'

Do i have to write `lambda_function(event,context)` for everything?

Comment: Yes, you have to. Because that way AWS knows which function to run.

Comment: @luk2302 and where do i have to put it for it to be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need it. It should be

```
import boto3
import botocore

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.list_buckets()
    print('Existing buckets:')
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        print(f'  {bucket["Name"]}')
```

because AWS needs to know / have a function to invoke and pass its `event` and `context` parameters.

Comment: when i put it there, it gives me the error "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function'", do you know what can it be?

Comment: @Hamilton sorry, blindly copied your code which was missing an indentation. Should work *now*.

Comment: tysm! it worked now, you saved my day haha